# ParamArray in xlWings

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

Is there a way to pass an unknown list of variables to an UDF in xlWings?

e.g. this python code:

```
def redistribute_with_old(dfFC, dfHist, columns=['site_name'])
```

does not work with this vba:

```
Function redistribute_with_old(dfFC, dfHist, ParamArray Columns())
```

columns results in a pyldispatch instead of a list. If that doesn't work, how does one create a function which accepts an unknown amount of variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It was as easy as to declare the last variable as *args in the xlwings module. After importing the UDF, the VBA code generates itself. Beautiful :)